# Combining multiple items by condition within a single list

Tags: dart

As in Dart you can combine several list items into one according to the following condition:

Given `List<String> arr = ['2','3','b','*','4','5','6','-','3','4'];`

Get `arr = ['23','b','*','456','-','34'];`

The list is unknown in advance. It can be of any length and with any sequence of characters. And need to combine only the lines that have numbers in them.

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: You want to combine entries which consists of only *single* digits, only digits, or which end/start with digits? What would you do for `['a2', '3', '', '4*5', '66', '7b']`?

Comment: Does the list consist of only single characters?

Comment: Items in the original list will always consist of a single character. Need to combine characters that are numbers and stand next to each other: '2', '3', '4' => '234' If the string-number is broken by any other sign, then nothing happens: '2', '-', '3' => '2', '-', '3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not describing what should happen if there are multiple special characters or letters. So I have made my example so it will only combine numbers:

```
void main() {
  final arr = ['2', '3', 'b', '*', '4', '5', '6', '-', '3', '4'];
  print(combine(arr)); // [23, b, *, 456, -, 34]
}

List<String> combine(List<String> input) {
  final output = <String>[];
  final buffer = StringBuffer();

  for (final string in input) {
    if (int.tryParse(string) == null) {
      if (buffer.isNotEmpty) {
        output.add(buffer.toString());
        buffer.clear();
      }
      output.add(string);
    } else {
      buffer.write(string);
    }
  }

  if (buffer.isNotEmpty) {
    output.add(buffer.toString());
  }

  return output;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I'm trying to learn Dart, and although the language documentation is good, there are not enough practical examples. Yes, this solution does exactly what I wanted. I plan to use it, but first I want to know the following: I get the arr list from a string using the split() method. Is it possible to convert the string immediately to a list where digit are combined into numbers? And will it be more effective than the combine function?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to use a regular expression to extract the numbers directly. But if you want to ask for details how to do that, please create an another question for that with an example of the input and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `''.join()` here:

```
arr = [''.join(arr[0:2]), arr[2], arr[3], ''.join(arr[4:7]), arr[7], ''.join(arr[8:10])]
```

If you only want to have a condition where you only join numerical values then you can add a for loop beforehand.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't specify an important point in the question.

The list is unknown in advance. It can be of any length and with any sequence of characters. And need to combine only the lines that have numbers in them.

Comment: This does not appear to be Dart code. Possibly Python?